# How to resolve "Incompatible return value type (got "FancyCat", expected "Self")"

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, typechecking, self-type

Here's a minimal example I've written:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Protocol
from typing_extensions import Self


class Cat(Protocol):
    def add(self, other: Self) -> Self:
        ...
    def sub(self, other: Self) -> Self:
        ...


class FancyCat(Cat):
    def __init__(self, value: int):
        self._value = value

    def add(self, other: Self) -> Self:
        return FancyCat(self._value + other._value)

    def sub(self, other: Self) -> Self:
        return FancyCat(self._value - other._value)

fc = FancyCat(3)
fc2 = FancyCat(4)
fc.add(fc2)
```

If I try to type check it, I get

```py
$ mypy t.py
t.py:19: error: Incompatible return value type (got "FancyCat", expected "Self")  [return-value]
t.py:22: error: Incompatible return value type (got "FancyCat", expected "Self")  [return-value]
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I'm so confused - isn't `Self` `FancyCat` in this case?

How can I satisfy `mypy` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not guarantee that Self will be returned. For example, child classes will still return `FancyCat`, therefore `Self` annotation is invalid.

To get rid of errors, you can either:

a) make sure it's always `self.__class__` returned, which IS actual `Self`

```
def add(self, other: Self) -> Self:
    return self.__class__(self._value + other._value)
```

b) type with what you are actually returning, `FancyCat`

```
def sub(self, other: Self) -> FancyCat:
    return FancyCat(self._value - other._value)
```

Comment: your first sentence makes perfect sense, thanks, I hadn't considered that

Comment: or make the class `@final`

Comment: note `self.__class__` is fragile to subclasses using a different `__init__`